# Getting errors after copying existing project files into a new AndroidStudio Android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I was able to create a new project In Android Stdio which ran fine.

Then I copied many of the files from an old project into it, and tried to run it, but I got this error about AppTheme:

[image]

It talks about values-v21.xml which I didn't have before. What is that file? And how can I get around this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file. Change,

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

To,

```
android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

Comment: Try using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". Because most of the times, this works for me.

Comment: One possible issue is that I copied the new files via the file system, but the file structure that I see in Android Studio doesn't reflect that yet. How can I get the file structure in UdemyStudio to get updated to reflect the changes in the file system?

Comment: Well, I don't think this issue is due to that reason. The problem is your project cannot find values-v21.xml in values folder. So best option is to change the theme to something that doesn't have v21 values.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand - is the v21 file something that is theme-specific?

Comment: Yes, you can read more on themes and how they work in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the file name. Your file is named **"values-v21.xml"**, all the android projects I saw had that file name as **"styles.xml"** and was included inside the v21 folder.  [Also I included an image. Sorry for the poor resolution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQS9T.png)

Also, v21 means that it's for API Level 21 and above. API Level 21 is Android 5.0 (Lollipop). For more info on API Level 21: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

I hope this fixes your problem.